# Looking for list of Android phones that have Vibrator amplitude control

Tags: android, vibration, amplitude

we are building an app that uses the Vibrator class for a research project.

We are trying to select a phone that allows the vibration amplitude to be programmatically modified.

I know for example the Pixel 2 XL has it but the Samsung A40 doesn't just from my own limited testing.

Does anyone know a resource (URL) that lists the phone capabilities so we can select a phone that has the above vibration amplitude feature?

a bit like https://www.productchart.com/smartphones/ but with more detailed hardware descriptions

Regards,
            Daniel.